# How to analyze a .dmp file?

Tags: dump

I know that this question was ask often but i cant really find a working program that allows me to read a .dmp file

I need this program to read a crashed TeamSpeak 3 .dmp file

The website `http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm%5ename=Analyze.htm` worked for me but the support has been withdrawn.

Is there a clone of this website that has the same method?

regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General issues can be addressed with DebugDiag tool http://debugdiag.com
If you'd like to go deeper - use WinDbg https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-using-windbg-preview